# Need help making ArrayList

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I am trying to create an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) using at least six Person objects that will contain user inputted name and age resulting in information being printed out in alphabetical order.

Array list that contains person:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Categorization  
{
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        System.out.println("Please enter a name " + name); // Can't return values
        String nameEntry = input.toString();

        System.out.println("Please enter an age " + age);
        int ageEntry = input.nextInt();

    }
  }
```

I am unfamiliar with creating classes and feel like this is where most of my errors occur.

```
    class Person
    {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public Person(String name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;

        }
```

Tried to return name and age but they are not going back to the Public Class

```
        public String getName() 
        {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge()
        {
            return age;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In the first block of code you aren't creating any Person's, but other than that it looks OK.

Comment: In the `System.out.println` sentence you are using the `name` and `age` without declaring it first. You need to store the values before using them.  After that, you can create Person objects, for example like this `Person  person = new Person(nameEntry, ageEntry);` and print the values `System.out.println("The name entry was "+person.getName());`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
public class Categorization {

    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        for(int i=1; i<=6; i++) {

            System.out.print("Please enter name for person " + i + " : ");
            String nameEntry = input.next();

            System.out.print("Please enter an age for person " + i + " : ");
            int ageEntry = input.nextInt();
            Person obj = new Person(nameEntry, ageEntry);
            people.add(obj);
        }

        System.out.println("List of entries you entered: ");
        for(Person obj: people) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + obj.getName() + " " + "Age: " + obj.getAge());
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

You need to create a Person object using `new` keyword to store respective values and then finally add it to the people list.